# android-studio: using SQLite class correct

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to use a SQLite Class in Android Studio outside the class. My error is:

Error:(42, 51) error: incompatible types: bluetooth cannot be converted to Context

"Bluetooth" is my calling class, I wan't receive some strings and write them to a SQLite DB.

How can I use the class correctly?

I try this: [Sqlite database can not be create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910395/sqlite-database-can-not-be-create) , but no luck. I don't understand the problem. :-/

Thanks for any help.

Here's my code:

DatabaseHelper.java:

```
   public class DatabaseHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "aprs";
    private final Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DBHelper helper;

    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // SQL statement to create book table
            String CREATE_POS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE pos ( " +
                    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "call TEXT, " +
                    "time TEXT )";

            // create books table
            db.execSQL(CREATE_POS_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older books table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");

            // create fresh books table
            this.onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public DatabaseHelper openDB(){
        helper = new DBHelper(context);
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void addPos(String call, String time) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("call", call);
        values.put("time", time);

        database.insert("pos",null, values);

        Log.e("DB", "written");
        database.close();
    }

    public void getAllPos() {
        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM pos;";

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("db", cursor.toString());
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is bluetooth.java, my calling class:

```
public class bluetooth extends Thread {
<snip>
        public void convertString() {
        DatabaseHelper entry = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        entry.addPos("text","test");
    }
<snap>      
}
```

Comment: Error is coming because bluetooth extends Thread and thread is not Context. to call DatabseHelper you will need Activity

Comment: For background operation, check out the Android [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class

Comment: Okay, I'm looking for AsyncTask.